# How can I check if a string only contains uppercase or lowercase letters?

Tags: python, string

Return True if and only if there is at least one alphabetic character in s and the alphabetic characters in s are either all uppercase or all lowercase.

```
def upper_lower(s):

   """ (str) -> bool



>>> upper_lower('abc')
True
>>> upper_lower('abcXYZ')
False
>>> upper_lower('XYZ')
True
"""
```

Comment: try using `isalpha()`, `isupper()', `islower()`. No need to make functions when these are available as builtins.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is by far the most efficient way of doing this.

But if you'd like some pythonic flavor in your code, you can try this:

```
'abc'.isupper()
'ABC'.isupper()
'abcABC'.isupper()

upper_lower = lambda s: s.isupper() or s.islower()
```

Comment: you mean this `if s.isupper() or s.islower():` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes you are right. In that case, regex would be a better solution in terms of running time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

```
if re.match(r'(?:[A-Z]+|[a-z]+)$', s):
    print("True")
else:
    print("Nah")
```

We don't need to add start of the line anchor since `re.match` tries to match from the beginning of the string.

So it enters in to the `if` block only if the input string contains only lowercase letters or only uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
if re.search('^([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)$', s):
    # all upper or lower case
```

Explanation: `^` matches the beginning of the string, `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` are trivial matches, `+` matches one or more. `|` is the "OR" regex, finally `$` matches the end of the string.

Or, you can use `all` and check:

```
all(c.islower() for c in s)
# same thing for isupper()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all alphabetic characters and then check if all or upper or all are lower

```
a=[c for c in s if s.isalpha()]
if a:
    if "".join(a).isupper() or "".join(a).islower():
    print "yes"
```